# Related Quantity Differentials

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My book has the following question I have no idea how to solve. It is the only problem I don't understand in the chapter, I want to have an answer before I move on.

The question is:

For related quantities: x,y,z; consider the differentials of z(x,y) and y(x,z) show that

$${\left( {{{\delta y} \over {\delta x}}} \right)_z} + {\left( {{{\delta y} \over {\delta z}}} \right)_x}{\left( {{{\delta z} \over {\delta x}}} \right)_y} = 0$$
Therefore, show that $${\left( {{{\delta y} \over {\delta x}}} \right)_z}{\left( {{{\delta y} \over {\delta z}}} \right)_x}{\left( {{{\delta z} \over {\delta x}}} \right)_y} =  - 1$$

I don't really know how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x$, $y$ and $z$ are related, you may express $z$ as a function of $x$ and $y$: $z(x,y)$. This corresponds to some 2D surface $z(x,y)$.

Let us write the differential of $z$ (along $z(x,y)$ surface):
$$
dz=\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_{y}dx + \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)_{x}dy \tag 1.
$$

Now let us consider the intersection of $z(x,y)$ surface with $z=\mathrm{const}$ surface: this will be some 1D curve. $z=\mathrm{const}$ along this curve, so $dz=0$. So we can write along this curve:
$$
dz=0=\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_{y}dx + \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)_{x}dy \tag 2.
$$
$dx$ and $dy$ in $(2)$ are at $z=\mathrm{const}$. So you may divide the whole equation $(2)$ by $dx$:
$$
0=\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_{y} + \left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)_{x}\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)_z,\tag 3
$$
$$
\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)_{x}\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)_z=-\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_{y}.\tag 4
$$
Now we will use that
$$\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)_{y}=\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\right)_{y}}. \tag 5$$
Substituting $(5)$ in $(4)$ we get the result:
$$
\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)_{x}\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)_z\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}\right)_{y}=-1.\tag 6
$$
This is what you need. Please note, that your second equation is incorrect. You should have $\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right)_z$ in it instead of $\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\right)_z$. The mnemonic rule for this property is that all three partial derivatives are ready for "cancellation" (though, of course, the regular "cancellation" is not possible).